# Can I have a complete web app coded inside native container?

Tags: android, ios, html, cordova, safari

Let's say I have an existing web application (used by desktop users currently)
I decide to move this to app store without much modifications.

So I create a hybrid app and submit to the App Store.
That is I just use a UIWebView (IOS) and render my web app completely inside the native container?

My question is will I face any issues doing this?
Like would it behave exactly like on IOS Safari browser?
Would cookies and all work well inside native ccontainer?

Comment: Yes, Exactly Same. We have tried so many demo with phonegap(Cardova). We didn't face any issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a template for doing this in Android.  You can just download the zip and replace the example HTML code with your own and it should work. This template by default allows cookies and javascript.  There is no address bar or anything like that, but you could add that in yourself later if you needed it.  This is just a good place to start.

https://github.com/jakewp11/HTML5_Android_Template